# HTML5 with XHTML 1.0 syntax what does it mean?

Tags: html

Out teacher told us, that we use HTML5 with XHTML 1.0 syntax. What does it mean? Is this possible? We write only `<!DOCTYPE>` on the top of the `*.html` Is it valid? (In HTML5, yes, but what's with the XHTML part?)

Comment: I think that basically means that when you're coding HTML5 you must adhere to strict XML rules. i.e. attributes must be equal to a value. You can do this `<input type='text' required/>`, but you have to do this `<input type='text' required='required'/>` for it to be XHTML valid. There are many other rules that you need to abide by.

Comment: This topic can be a bit confusing. You may be misunderstanding your teacher, or they may be over-generalizing. Look at it a different way: HTML 5 is a standard and tells you exactly what is valid. Follow that standard and don't worry about what else it may or may not look like.

Comment: @kehrk: Since when were bit.ly links considered "great" for anything other than Twitter?

Comment: @BoltClock You should probably click it before getting your panties in a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can write HTML5 with XHTML 1.0 syntax, since HTML5 permits XML syntax and it explicitly allows an XHTML 1.0 doctype as “legacy doctype” in the [XHTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html).

But if you write just `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start, it does not conform to XHTML 1.0, which has specific [rules on the doctype thing](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative).

Using XHTML in documents to be delivered on the web is generally an exercise in futility. There is nothing to be gained. But when documents are to be delivered to software other than web browsers, such as e-book readers, using XHTML may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can just think that, XHTML is a blend of HTML and XML.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

You declare the `<!DOCTYPE html>` to help the IE better render the document. For more on that, you can refer to the following document: https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

I think your teacher just meant to say something like:

> When you're writing an HTML document, you must keep a note on the XML standards too.

For example,

```
<p>Start and end an element.</p>
```

And all other XML rules.

Comment: But those XML well-formedness rules don't always apply to HTML 5. They are valid, but there are exceptions, such as "A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by..." - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html